# Visual Studio - Terminate program execution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

If I run a program using `Start Without Debugging`, I want to be able to terminate that process. I am looking for a key combination or option in the menu to be able to do this. How can this be done?

I am **not** talking about terminating the program *while debugging*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that there is no 'yes' answer for this question. When you start without debugging it just launches a new, separate process and as such, it couldn't be terminated from within a Visual Studio.

The only different scenario I could find here, is when you are working on a web project, for which VS is launching a hosting process (a HTTP server, like IIS Express). If you kill your VS then, it will kill the process hosting a web application, so it is a kind of dependent process.

But still there's no shortcut for that. So that means there's no such way from VS.

Comment: Wow that is very disappointing and annoying. In Java editors all of them have the ability to terminate the process.